# How to find out how fc-match matches?

Tags: linux, fonts

When I run `fc-mach Sans`, it returns `DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"` but if it is run like `fc-match "Sans "` or `fc-match "Sans 9"` it returns `unifont.ttf: "unifont" "Medium"`. I prefer to always use DejaVu Sans but I can't figure out why fontconfig selects unifont. Neither the global nor the local config seems to mention unifont (`grep -ri unifont /etc/fonts/ ~/.fonts.conf` returns nothing). Playing with LC_DEBUG didn't help me either. Is there a way to get the information why fontconfig behaves like this?

Answer (score 14):

On a quick glance it looks like a genuine fontconfig bug to me, since it works properly here and I do have both DejaVu and Unifont installed:

```
$ fc-match Sans
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
$ fc-match "Sans"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
$ fc-match "Sans "
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
$ fc-match "Sans 9"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

But, on a closer look, we can see some more details. There still may be a fontconfig bug somewhere, but `fc-match` apparently returns a default value when it doesn't find anything. It is just the default is DejaVu on my system:

```
$ fc-match uni
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
$ fc-match unifont
Unifont.ttf: "unifont" "Medium"
$ fc-match 4e5zedrkbxp
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

The man page `fc-match(1)` confirms that the command does not do exact matching, but returns what it thinks are the best matches. You can see them all with `-a` or the more concise `-s`:

```
$ fc-match -s uni # now it also finds unifont
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Oblique"
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold Oblique"
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
helvR12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: "Helvetica" "Regular"
FreeSans.ttf: "FreeSans" "нормален"
KanjiStrokeOrders.ttf: "KanjiStrokeOrders" "Medium"
Eadui.ttf: "Eadui" "Medium"
Unifont.ttf: "unifont" "Medium"
FreeSerif.ttf: "FreeSerif" "нормален"
cu12.pcf.gz: "ClearlyU" "Regular"
cu-pua12.pcf.gz: "ClearlyU PUA" "Regular"
10x20.pcf.gz: "Fixed" "Regular"
```

Upon which you can simply say "screw you" and add another search on top of it to get matching the way you expect it:

```
$ fc-match -s uni | grep -i uni
Unifont.ttf: "unifont" "Medium"
```

But, your question is about how exactly it does the matching. `FcFontMatch(3)` and further roughly confirm that it uses a default/configured value and definitely confirms that it first modifies the search term you passed to it. For anything even deeper, you'll have to [inspect the code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/tree/) (start with the above mentioned function).

Answer (score 9):

FontConfig matched attributes based on the "distance" from the match criteria. If you want to see what is going on behind the scenes, then [set the environment variable](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) FC_DEBUG=3 and rerun your search. This will show debugging information that might be helpful. You shouldn't need to read FontConfig code.